# Remove the current item from a menu

Tags: categories, menus

I have a menu. It has two items:

- the first is a link ("Index", www.domain.com)
- the second one is a link to a category page

I have the requirement to remove the first link when I'm on the index page and remove the second link when I'm on that category.

Ideas?

Comment: possibly using `display: none;` with the css selector for the current menu item ?

Comment: The problem was getting the current menu item. But it turns out wordpress puts anchor css class in the current item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that this menu produces is this:

```
<ul id="dd" class="dd">
  <li id="menu-item-142" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-home menu-item-142">
    <a href="http://www.domain.com">Index</a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-102" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-102">
    <a href="http://www.domain.com/?page_id=82">Categories</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I fix it adding this to the css file:

```
#dd .current-menu-item {
   display:none !important;
}
```

Wordpress is kind enough to add anchor css styles that can be used. i have the `#dd` prefix so that this only works on this menu and not all the others.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This would only work if the only two pages were the Home and Cat page. The OP made it sound like they may have more than the two pages. For example: If i had a "contact" page this would hide that from the menu when on that page.

Comment: @BandonRandon, that is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probally want to use [WP Conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) and do something like this:

```
if(is_home()){
   //show home  menu
}
else if(is_page('mypage')){
   //show category menu for JUST that page
}
else{
//show the menu for all other pages
}
```

What you do inside each conditional statement is up to you. Here are 3 solutions:

1. Use CSS and hide a class `<style type="text/css">menu-item-### {display:none;}</style>` You'd want put this solution in your `<head>`
2. Create 2 or 3 menus and then call each menu depending on which page the user is on
3. Add and use the exclude hook as [described here](http://ehsanis.me/2010/11/30/wordpress-wp_nav_menu-to-exclude-pages/)

This could be modified depending on your needs.

Hope that at least gets you going in the right direction.